# Google DisplayVideo -360 (DV360) Daily limit exceeded error

Tags: google-api, dv360

We have an app which uses different APIs like dv360 and google ads. The issue is that we are facing Daily limit exceeded exception very frequently. We have checked project dashboard to cross verify if we are actually hitting the quota. However, we found that we are not hitting the allowed quota for any of these APIs but still we are getting this error.

Can someone point out what can be the reason for the error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message.   Which quota exactly are you hitting.   There are a number of daily limit quotas.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to understand is that the dashboard is not perfect it is not accurate by any sense of the word.  it is an estimate and it is not real-time.

What you should check is the error message that you are getting this is the truth. You would not get that error message unless you where hitting the quota limit.

The first thing that you should do is check your code and ensure that you are not hitting the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/limits) defined on that page.

if you are hitting the limit and you cant reduce the number of requests you are making then you will need to request a quota extension.

[image]